# Close multiple DIV elements with a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, syntax, function

I need a small function for jQuery that would close multiple DIV elements, but I'm having trouble with JS syntax.

I got this far:

`function closePanels{

    $("#servicesPanel").hide("fast");

    $("#portfolioPanel").hide("fast");

    $("#contactPanel").hide("fast");

    $("#aboutPanel").hide("fast");

};`

Sounds logical to me: That way I want to call the function from various points in the DOM. Where do I get it wrong? How do I write this function so it'll work?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you may want to get a good JavaScript book, and do a sit down with it.  Get yourself a bit more familiar with the language before you continue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ohhh, So close!

this:

```
function closePanels{
```

needs to be:

```
function closePanels () {
```

Note the addition of brackets (cause it's a function).

Comment: Thanks. BTW: how do I call it from another function?

Comment: Same way as any language - `closePanels()`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the missing () why dont you give give each panel div a class of say panel. This will allow you to code less hide methods by saying just

```
$('div.panel').hide();
```

Of course you may have more panels and you dont wish to hide them all but i cannot tell without the markup. its merely an option.

Comment: My project has few ID elements ("#portfolioPanel" for example, is one of them). I need to open them individually and close them all at once, form various points of the website.

That's why (I think) I need this function, so I can call it form where ever, when ever, to just reset things for the user.